# Disable validity check on memcache key in Zend_cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached

`Zend/Cache/Core.php` has a `_validateIdOrTag` function which restricts characters allowed in keys to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

**Q1: Is it what the below quote from the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html#zend.cache.backends.memcached) means?**

> Be careful : with this backend, "tags" are not supported for the
>   moment as the "doNotTestCacheValidity=true" argument.

If so, **Q2: why impose such a restriction? (using characters such as `-` or `/` to cache URL content is very common, the `memcache pecl` extension does allow these characters)?**

If not, **Q3: is there an option to disable that limitation? (I couldn't find one)?**

Answer (score 1):

**1. Tags**

Tags let you group cached items together into sets and to mutate these sets based on the tag. For example, in a blog you may cache all your posts and tag them with `"post"`. You could then delete all items tagged with `"post"` at the same time. However this is not supported with memcache at the moment.

**2. Key Restrictions**

The restriction is not on the contents of the cache but the key used to access them. You can therefore store whatever you want, URLs, special characters etc. You just need to make sure your key does not contain them.

If you are concerned about it, just md5 your key to ensure it is a valid key and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on `tags`, sounds very handy. Regarding the `keys`, I probably wasn't clear enough: the idea is to use the `URL` as a key, for instance to serve content directly from your webserver (http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/).  I still don't get why `Zend_Cache` is imposing such restrictions, `memcached` is perfectly find with non-alphanumeric keys, so why taking that away.

Comment: About the `md5`: workaround I would be reluctant to use it for the risk of collision which would cause the application to use the same key for different content types. I would rather use `base64` or other non-hashing methods if I had too, but in my case I simply won't use `Zend_Cache` and use the `Pecl memcache` instead if I can't get rid of these restrictions (without rewriting the source code), being able to use non-alphanumeric characters in keys is just too valuable.